# Editing HTML structure of Gutenberg layout recent post?

Tags: block-editor, recent-posts

I used gutenberg layout method with wordpress editor to call recent posts.
Wordpress automatically generated this HTML structure.

```
<ul class="wp-block-latest-posts__list has-dates wp-block-latest-posts">
   <li>
     <div class="wp-block-latest-posts__featured-image">
       <img loading="lazy" width="1024" height="663" src="" alt="" class="wp-image-73" 
            srcset="" sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px">
     </div>
     <a href="">SOME TEXT</a>
     <time datetime="2021-05-08T17:21:16+00:00" class="wp-block-latest-posts__post-date">May 8, 
           2021</time>
     <div class="wp-block-latest-posts__post-excerpt">SOME TEXT</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Now I need to group anchor, time and the last div tag in another div tag for my CSS design.
Problem is I do not know how to edit html structure of recent post with wordpress editor. Should I code?

[image]

clicking over SOME POST doesn't give me a chance to create a new div there..
I use underscore theme.

I DON'T WANT USE PLUGINS IF IT IS POSSIBLE WITHOUT PLUGIN

Comment: Does [this](https://www.boldgrid.com/support/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-use-the-code-editor-in-the-gutenberg-editor/) help?

Comment: That structure is generated by the code in [wp-includes/blocks/latest-posts.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.7.1/wp-includes/blocks/latest-posts.php#L100). You can't just edit the generated output, you'll need to change the structure in the code that generates it. I don't know Gutenberg well but I'd guess you'll have to clone the latest-posts block and customise the cloned copy.

Comment: This is more of a hint than an answer but I modify the classes of some core block output in a js file like this https://github.com/RelevanceDigital/wp-bs4-starter-theme/blob/master/js/gutenberg.js the file gets enqueued in the functions file here: https://github.com/RelevanceDigital/wp-bs4-starter-theme/blob/master/functions.php#L261